# Pjsip Android: Video Call - Window Preview size issue(SurfaceView is used to display video frames)

Tags: android, surfaceview, pjsip

I am trying to build SIP call application using Pjsip and so far it is working good.

I am facing one issue in displaying video window.
I am using surface view to display streaming frames.

Please see the attached image below:

[image]

I want to remove Black space on both side of my preview.

UI Part:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceIncomingVideo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfacePreviewCapture"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_100sdp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_70sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_130sdp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                app:elevation="0dp">

                <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                        android:id="@+id/layoutCall"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/ivBack"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/ivBack">

                        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                            android:id="@+id/ivHabariLogo"
                            android:layout_width="27dp"
                            android:layout_height="37dp"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/call_ic_habari_logo" />

                        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/helvetica_neue_regular"
                            android:text="@string/toolbar_title_video"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_14ssp"
                            android:textColor="@color/grey"
                            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/ivHabariLogo"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivHabariLogo"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/ivHabariLogo" />
                    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivBack"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                        android:paddingStart="21dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/back_arrow_white" />

                </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutUser"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_24sdp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_100sdp" >
                <RippleBackground
                    android:id="@+id/callRinging"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:rb_color="@color/ringing_1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    app:rb_duration="2500"
                    app:rb_radius="@dimen/_40sdp"
                    app:rb_rippleAmount="3"
                    app:rb_scale="2">

                </RippleBackground>

                <RadarViewUsersView
                    android:id="@+id/radarViewUser"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_100sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_100sdp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">

                </RadarViewUsersView>
            </FrameLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/tvCalleeName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_16ssp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/helvetica_neue_regular" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/tvCallState"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:text="@string/sip_call_state_calling"
                android:fontFamily="@font/helvetica_neue_regular"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_2sdp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutOutgoingCall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_24sdp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivEndCall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:padding="@dimen/_16sdp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_call_reject" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivSwitchCamera"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.33"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_switch_camera" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivDisableVideoCall"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.33"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_8sdp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_video_cam_off" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivMuteVoiceCall"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.33"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_video_mic_on" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutIncomingCall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_16sdp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivRejectCall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_call_reject" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivAcceptCall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_call_accept" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Code Part:
In onCreate():

```
surfaceIncomingVideo.holder.addCallback(this)
surfacePreviewCapture.holder.addCallback(previewHandler)
```

When preview received:

```
fun updateVideoPreview(holder: SurfaceHolder) {
        if (SipManager.currentCall != null &&
                SipManager.currentCall?.mVideoWindow != null &&
                SipManager.currentCall?.mVideoPreview != null) {
            if (videoPreviewActive) {
                val vidWH = VideoWindowHandle()
                vidWH.handle?.setWindow(holder.surface)
                val vidPrevParam = VideoPreviewOpParam()
                vidPrevParam.window = vidWH
                try {
                    SipManager.currentCall?.mVideoPreview?.start(vidPrevParam)
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    println(e)
                }

            } else {
                try {
                    SipManager.currentCall?.mVideoPreview?.stop()
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    println(e)
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help me with that?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: post some code to check

Comment: @LakhwinderSingh Do you need UI file or code file?

Comment: both would be good, otherwise, code can help

Comment: Post some relevant code which you have tried.

Comment: I have updated the post with code. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so finally I got an answer. It was because of orient I ahve set to rotate my camera view. I think it's internal pjsip issue.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, Could you please elaborate you answer. I'm facing the issue with remote window as well. https://ibb.co/sjb5y0r

Answer (score 0):

I won't go into ultra details on how to do this but the general idea is this:

A) This is a known / accepted issue with PJSIP. The developer(s) have stated that its "to be expected".

B) The way around this takes a few hoops to jump through:

1. Add a header to outgoing calls stating your current orientation. DO NOT, change it using PJSIP.
2. Have your SIP server forward this header to the target client.
3. Have the target client read this header and rotate the video on the android end.

I am dealing with this as we speak and have the orientation arriving at my view. I'm fairly new to android development so I now need to figure out how to rotate a surfaceview (setRotation not working...) and after how to send an additional request to the client when the orientation changes.

But thats the basic idea... If you want to get rid of the bars and deal with the black bars, thats the route to go.